# Redirect to an external URL using meteor router

Tags: meteor

I am using the meteor router package. I want to redirect to an external URL from  the meteor app. That is, when I point my app url to `http://localhost:3000/goexternal`, it should go to an external site.

Is there some way we can do this with the router package? If the router package doesn't support this requirement, how can we do a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to put the redirect in middleware:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(0, 0, {
  route: '/goexternal',
  handle: function(req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(302, {
      'Location': 'http://whatever',
    });
    res.end();
  },
});
```

Comment: if we want to update a collection based on the url parameters, how should I do it? I tried find query inside the handle function and I got "Error: Can't wait without a fiber".

Comment: Wrap the code that access db in `Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){...});`.

Comment: Putting it inside the Fiber(function() {...} worked for me. Thanks Hubert for helping out.